# encoding a list of key/value pairs into a URL request parameter

Tags: jsf, servlets, servlet-3.0

Is there a standard API call (or set of calls) that allows me to encode a list of key/value pairs into a SINGLE request parameter?  Somehow I have never done this before.

What I am looking for is to generate a URL which encodes an arbitrarily long string of parameters that will be decoded by the indicated page.  For example:

```
http://someth.ing/page?params=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where the xxxxxxx is the encoded form of a

```
Map<String, String>
```

or if that isn't available then a

```
List<String>
```

I know my alternative is to just encode each key as its own request parameter, but that creates a lot of parsing work on the decoding side I would rather avoid.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no standard. To automate things, I would design a prefix and add it to the name of the keys as params (something like '?mymap_key1=value1&mymap_key2=value2...`. Retrieving all parameters, checking for the prefix and rebuilding the map can be done by a helper routine that can be reused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just convert to/from [JSON](http://json.org). You could use among others [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this:

```
Map<String, String> data = createItSomehow();
String dataAsJson = new Gson().toJson(data);
String url = "http://example.com/some?data=" + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
// ...
```

And in the other side, assuming a servlet:

```
String dataAsJson = request.getParameter("data");
Map<String, String> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
// ...
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea I hadn't considered.  A big advantage of using JSON is that it would make processing on the client side (if I ever wanted to) much easier.  I'll play with it over the next couple of days and report back.